# Protractor - Jasmine2 async timeout error occurs very randomly for e2e tests

Tags: javascript, selenium, backbone.js, jasmine, protractor

From time to time I am experiencing strange issue during running my e2e tests.

```
Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
```

Page is developed in backbone.js
Protractor ver: ^2.4.0
Jasmine ver: 2
chromedriver: 2.19.0",

The issue occurs very often running on selenium grid but sometimes as well simple run the test on my browser is failed. And what I've noticed during running tests on my browser is that sometimes browser freezes and so that this error occured. It's very random.

My spec:

```
var WelcomePage = require('../pages/welcome_page.js');
var LogInToSystem = require('../helper.methods/system_authentication');
var EnvironmentInitializer = require('../setup/environment_initializer');

describe('Test -> Welcome page', function () {

    var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
    var welcomePage = new WelcomePage();
    var originalTimeout;

    var increaseTimeouts = function() {
        originalTimeout = jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL;
        jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = WAIT_TIMEOUT * 50;
    };

    beforeAll(function () {
        increaseTimeouts();
        LogInToSystem.asAdmin();
        EnvironmentInitializer.prepareEnvironment();
        welcomePage.logout('environment preparation');
        jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = originalTimeout;
    });

    beforeEach(function () {
        increaseTimeouts();
        LogInToSystem.asAdmin2();
    });

    afterEach(function () {
        welcomePage.logout();
        jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = originalTimeout;
    });


    it('should verify dropdown is not visible after clicking away', function () {
        clickWithWait(welcomePage.loginButton);
        browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(welcomePage.logoutButton), WAIT_TIMEOUT, 'logoutButton was not visible ');
        clickWithWait(welcomePage.usersButton);
        browser.wait(EC.invisibilityOf(welcomePage.logoutButton), WAIT_TIMEOUT, 'logoutButton was not invisible ');
    });
});
```